# Orangescrum says "Wrong database information. Please try with correct information." even though I've provided correct credentials

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, php, mysql

[image]

I'm entering correct database credentials. I've seen similar post in stackoverflow, which was left unanswered. Hoping for replies here.

Comment: 1) What is the problem? 2) You wrote: `Then I setup a virtual host orangescrum.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d.`  Why did you write the VirtualHost with those options? 3) My guess is that your server is presenting a directory listing which is almost always wrong. 4) Do **NOT** use screenshots for text. Also, your image does not show the details I would like to see. It stops at **images**. Typical files that Apache is looking for start with `index`. Delete the image in your post and replace it with text. 5) You have included details that are not relevant. Research your problem before posting.